Calling a function from another service in google cloud
I have already seen that some people have faced this problem but I have not seen a solution.
I have a lot of modules deployed on google cloud and each of them has a cloudbuild.yaml file to be built on the cloud.
However several methods are duplicated and I would like to import these methods from a module that would be common to all without losing the possibility of building my modules separately.
The simple 'require' of node.js only works locally but once on the cloud we lose the links between the library and the module.
I have this scheme :

`root/
├── module1/
│   └── package.json
│   └── index.js
|   └── cloudbuild.yaml
├── module2/
│   └── package.json
│   └── index.js
|   └── cloudbuild.yaml
├── module3/
│   └── package.json
│   └── index.js
|   └── cloudbuild.yaml`


If anyone has a solution thanks to him.
Currently I thought about this type of scheme but by doing this I would lose the possibility of building my services separately and this is not what I want  :
`root/
├── common/
│   └── package.json
│   └── index.js
├── module1/
│   └── package.json
│   └── index.js
├── module2/
│   └── package.json
│   └── index.js
├── module3/
│   └── package.json
│   └── index.js
└── cloudbuild.yaml`


What I'm hearing in your question is that you have multiple modules where some modules are going to leverage some common code.  You are finding that there is a puzzle because you want to "block out" the common code so that it can be found/used by Cloud Build but it appears that Node.js require wants the packages to be local to be found.
One possible solution is to "package" your common logic as a Node.js package (think npm).  You could then employ Google Artifact Registry which has the ability to serve npm packages.  I am now imagining that you your build process has a step that packages your common libraries into an npm package and adds them to Artifact Registry.  Then, in the other modules that want to use those packages, you would refer to your Artifact Registry entries in your module's package.json.  By using Artifact Registry, you are effectively creating your own private npm repository and assuring consistency/simplicity between your modules.
A reference to using Node.js packages with Artifact Registry can be found here.
